# how to render pdf's dynamically in react?

Tags: reactjs

if I import the file I can render it but not dynamically from a path

I have tried using both react-pdf, iframe.

Below are working,

```
 import pdf from './shared/B.pdf';
 <Document file={pdf}> <Page pageNumber={1} /> </Document> 
 <iframe src= {pdf}/>
```

Below are not working,

```
<Document file='./shared/B.pdf'> <Page pageNumber={1} /> </Document> 
<iframe src= './shared/B.pdf'/>
```

I need it without import as I will get file path at runtime. Can anyone help?

Comment: The issue does not come from react itself but more from your bundler. Which one are you using ? I am pretty sure you don't have a shared folder in your public directory. Somehow you need to configure your bundler to create a shared folder with the given pdfs in your public directory.

Comment: I have created the app using create-react-app.

Comment: Move your shared folder within the public folder then.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

try [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

this library make really easy PDF embedding in react, like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file="somefile.pdf"
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
        <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can se from the source code of the library, render a PDF in react it is not as straightforward as you could think.

Another method is to use `<embed />`:

```
<embed src="files/myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

Comment: This code I already tried if I don't import pdf it's failing.

Comment: PDF must be copied as asset in webpack configuration or retrieved simply by url in a public folder

Answer (score 0):

When you use import, the bundler that comes with create-react-app automatically packages the imported resource within the build sources.

If you want to use files without importing them, you need to somehow configure your bundler to package those files.

The easiest way to achieve that with create-react-app is to move the wanted files in the [public folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder).

So if you have the following directory structure this should work:

```
public
|-- shared
|  |-- B.pdf
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use dynamic import -

```
const pdf = /* name received dynamically */
import(´${pdf}´);
```

Read more about dynamic import - https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports